# AndroidStudio 1.3: 'Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation' error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am getting the above error in when I try and run tests because I can no longer use the 'provided' keyword for non-jar dependencies in gradle build scripts as of the latest AndroidStudio update to 1.3.

I have a relatively simple Gradle build script that has worked until the latest AndroidStudio update.

- The main application compiles a library project which depends on Google play services.
- I also have a Testutils project I compile for tests only via an 'androidTestCompile' command in the main build script. This project also depends on Google Play services.
- Up until now to avoid 'Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation' errors I used the 'Provided' keyword in place of the 'compile' keyword in the TestUtils' gradle build script to reference the dependency on Google Play services.
- As of the latest AS update, I get the following warning and the tests no longer compile: 'Warning:Project TestUtils: provided dependencies can only be jars. com.google.android.gms:play-services:aar:6.1.71 is an Android Library'.

How can I resolve this issue?

Many thanks in advance,
Riz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following configuration to my app level build.gradle to exclude play services from the androidTestCompile for TestUtils. This fixed the issue:

```
configurations {
    androidTestCompile.exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    androidTestCompile.exclude module: 'play-services:6.1.71'
}
```